In Matter.js, using SVG objects created "fromVertices" I can't "applyForce" or setVelocity on those bodies
When adding convex SVGs to a matter.js canvas (using the polyfills so they look fine) the movement of these bodies when forces are applied is not correct. I can barely move the bodies at all even when applying forces or setting velocity directly.
I have a matter.js canvas, and I am adding SVGs like this:
(code is a bit out of context, but hopefully this is enough to get the idea)
let svgBody = Bodies.fromVertices(
  (ltr.x * matterContainer.clientWidth),
  SVG_STARTING_Y_AS_PRCNT * matterContainer.clientHeight,
  [vertices],
  {
  //   friction: 3,
  //   frictionAir: 0.00001,
  restitution: 0.8,
  //   density: 0.42,
  label: "Letter",
  render: {
    fillStyle: "#00cc00",
    strokeStyle: "#00cc00",
    lineWidth: 1
    }
  }
);

As you can see, I'm playing with adding removing friction and other properties because when these objects collide with other objects they don't move much at all.
Within a collision when I do:
Body.setVelocity(b, { x: 0, y: -10 });
Body.setAngularVelocity( b, 0.5 );

(b is the svg body)
nothing happens.
I even tried "reversing" gravity by adding the body to a collection (antiGravs) that is getting this code applied :
Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function() {
                        var gravity = engine.world.gravity;
          
                        antiGravs.forEach((bdy) => {
                            Body.applyForce(bdy, bdy.position, {
                                x: -gravity.x * gravity.scale * bdy.mass,
                                y: -gravity.y * gravity.scale * bdy.mass
                            });
                        })
                    });

When I add other bodies to that collection -- I can throw them around with my mouse and they defy gravity, but not the SVG ones.
In the browser, here is what one of the SVG bodies looks like property wise:
angle: 0
anglePrev: -0.5
angularSpeed: 0.5
angularVelocity: 0.5
area: 704.3456252241083
axes: (2) [{…}, {…}]
bounds: {min: {…}, max: {…}}
chamfer: null
circleRadius: 0
collisionFilter: {category: 1, mask: 4294967295, group: 0}
constraintImpulse: {x: 0, y: 0, angle: 0}
density: 0
events: null
force: {x: 0, y: 0}
friction: 0.01
frictionAir: 0.01
frictionStatic: 0.5
id: 165
inertia: NaN
inverseInertia: NaN
inverseMass: Infinity
isSensor: false
isSleeping: false
isStatic: false
label: "Letter"
mass: 0
motion: 0
parent: {id: 167, type: 'body', label: 'Letter', parts: Array(3), plugin: {…}, …}
parts: [{…}]
plugin: {}
position: {x: 430.4627809892338, y: 195.48627853966926}
positionImpulse: {x: 0, y: 0}
positionPrev: {x: 430.0888761241821, y: 205.808158019019}
render: {visible: true, opacity: 1, strokeStyle: '#00cc00', fillStyle: '#00cc00', lineWidth: 1, …}
restitution: 0.9
sleepCounter: 0
sleepThreshold: 60
slop: 0.05
speed: 10
timeScale: 1
torque: 0
totalContacts: 0
type: "body"
velocity: {x: 0, y: -10}
vertices: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
_original: null


Can you share a [mcve], with full (but minimal) code and an SVG so I can run it, see the problem, and then provide a solution?

It'll take a little bit of doing, but I'll put one together.

I kind of solved my own problem while trying to create a minimal reproducible example (which was working) -- turns out the bodyA, and bodyB that I get in a collision are not the actual bodies? So I'm mapping them back to the original using the 'label' attribute which allows me to setVelocity on the original bodies... this is obviously not the right way, when I figure out the right way, I'll post my solution

Glad to hear--looking forward to the solution and minimal example. It should be useful to future visitors. Funny how minimizing the problem often solves it.
